# upload media to wordpress rest api

Tags: c#, wordpress, rest, xamarin, httpclient

Anybody have ever successful upload file to wordpress using their rest api? I can create the media but the content is not uploaded when I check from wordpress admin. here is the code to upload it

```
public async Task<Author> UpdateProfilePicture(byte[] imageSource, string filename)
        {
            try
            {
                var url = Constants.BaseEndpoint + "/media";
                var header = ServiceHelpers.GetOauthHeader(url, "POST");
                var followCategory = string.Empty;
                using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                {

                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", header);
                    var requestContent = new MultipartFormDataContent();
                    var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(imageSource);
                    imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
                    imageContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
                    {
                        FileName = filename + ".jpg"
                    };
                    requestContent.Add(imageContent);
                    var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, requestContent);
                    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                    {
                        var rawResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        var parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Author>(rawResponse);
                        return parsedResponse;
                    }
                    throw new Exception("Not success");
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
            }
        }
```

Comment: are you getting a success response?  Have you checked for logs on the WP side to see if it has any useful information?

Comment: Yes the response is 201 (created) but the image is not uploaded

Comment: https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-rest-api-log/

Comment: you meman I need to install that plugin and check from the log right?

Comment: You need to check the WP/PHP/server logs.  I have no idea what your setup is or what logs you have access to - that link is just a suggested plugin that might help you

Comment: Did you solve this? having this question aswell

Answer (score 0):

Wordpress REST API responses are usually pretty good at indicating why they're failing, if you'll look at the response :) Here's what I get w/ your code:

```
{"code":"rest_upload_unknown_error","message":"Specified file failed upload test.","data":{"status":500}}
```

Remove the MultipartFormDataContent - just send the ByteArrayContent.

```
    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
    {
        httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", header);
        var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(imageSource);
        imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");
        imageContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
        {
            FileName = filename + ".jpg"
        };
        var response = await httpClient.PostAsync(url, imageContent);
        var rawResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var parsedResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<JObject>(rawResponse, new JsonSerializerSettings { DateParseHandling = DateParseHandling.None });
            var mediaItemId = (string)parsedResponse["id"];
            var mediaItemUrl = (string)parsedResponse["source_url"];
            Console.WriteLine("new media item id = " + mediaItemId);
            Console.WriteLine("new media item url = " + mediaItemUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Not success. Response from wordpress: " + rawResponse);
        }
    }
```